# Heroku spring app builds successfully but failed to run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I have build an web application using Spring and it is working in localhost. The build is successful when I deployed it to heroku with the following logs

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 11... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] -------------------------< sg.edu.iss:mytrial >-------------------------
       [INFO] Building mytrial 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:list (default-cli) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
       [INFO] Copying 27 resources
       [INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 57 source files to /tmp/build_901df98b/target/classes
       [INFO] /tmp/build_901df98b/src/main/java/sg/edu/iss/ca/controller/MyErrorController.java: /tmp/build_901df98b/src/main/java/sg/edu/iss/ca/controller/MyErrorController.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
       [INFO] /tmp/build_901df98b/src/main/java/sg/edu/iss/ca/controller/MyErrorController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_901df98b/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /tmp/build_901df98b/target/test-classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_901df98b/target/mytrial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:repackage (repackage) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mytrial ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_901df98b/target/mytrial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/sg/edu/iss/mytrial/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mytrial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_901df98b/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/sg/edu/iss/mytrial/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mytrial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  11.243 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-10T02:49:37Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 102.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v30
       https://cims-spring.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

However, when I tried to run the app, the following error shows in my heroku logs:

```
2021-03-10T02:51:20.125315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cims-spring.herokuapp.com request_id=e3bf1cbe-0a85-46a6-91c5-e9be443b8724 fwd="220.255.55.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-10T02:51:20.565627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cims-spring.herokuapp.com request_id=540479be-1d1b-4504-b2b2-90605841225f fwd="220.255.55.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The repository for the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Tingkai911/java_ca)

Please help, I have tried everything I can find in google and I am out of ideas

Answer (score -1):

Heroku uses OpenJDK 8 to run your application by default, to change version you have to add a file called system.properties to your application.

Set a property java.runtime.version in the file:

```
  java.runtime.version=11
```

To know more about it check here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support

If possible you can change your java version 11 to 8, this will be more easier to deploy your application on Heroku with java 8 by default.

Comment: Hi, I have already done that and I think the app is already running in Java 11. The problem is still there